# React js запись в local storage_2

Tags: reactjs, localstorage

После добавления любых двух задач(они сохраняются в local storage)
При нажатия на иконку карандаш(появляется форма с кнопкой редактировать)и внесения изменения в задачу, происходит редактирование,а в хранилище данныестарые. Я так пониманию, надо записать снова в local storage. Помогите, как не пытался, пока не смог. Думаю в updateTodo ерорка. Путь в репозитории: react-todo-app3/src/components/TodoList.js
Сайт: https://react-todo-app3.vercel.app
Репозиторий на гит: https://github.com/paul76546/react-todo-app3

````
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import TodoForm from './TodoForm';
import Todo from './Todo';

function TodoList() {
  //const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);переделываем на 
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(localStorage.getItem('todos') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos')) : []);
  
  //добавляем еще одну функцию
  const setTodosWithSave = (newTodos) => {
    setTodos(newTodos);
    localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(newTodos))
};

  const addTodo = todo => {
    if (!todo.text || /^\s*$/.test(todo.text)) {
      return;
    }

    const newTodos = [todo, ...todos];

    setTodosWithSave(newTodos);
    console.log(...todos);
  };
//перед консоль лог было setTodos(newTodos);
  

  const updateTodo = (todoId, newValue) => {
    if (!newValue.text || /^\s*$/.test(newValue.text)) {
      return;
    }

    setTodos(prev => prev.map(item => (item.id === todoId ? newValue : item)));
    

  };
//34  строка?
  const removeTodo = id => {
    const removedArr = [...todos].filter(todo => todo.id !== id);

    setTodosWithSave(removedArr);
  };

  const completeTodo = id => {
    let updatedTodos = todos.map(todo => {
      if (todo.id === id) {
        todo.isComplete = !todo.isComplete;
      }
      return todo;
    });
    setTodosWithSave(updatedTodos);
  };

  
  //let toLocal = reactLocalStorage.setObject('var', {'test': 'test'});?????How
  
  //h1 заголовок Какие планы на сегодня? 
  // (What's the Plan for Today?) по английскому
  // меняю на Список дел на сегодня
  //ставлю обратно 
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Список дел на сегодня</h1>
      <TodoForm onSubmit={addTodo} />
      <Todo
        todos={todos}
        completeTodo={completeTodo}
        removeTodo={removeTodo}
        updateTodo={updateTodo}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default TodoList;```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перепишите функцию `updateTodo` следующим образом:

```
const updateTodo = (todoId, newValue) => {
    if (!newValue.text || /^\s*$/.test(newValue.text)) {
      return;
    }

    setTodosWithSave(todos.map(item => (item.id === todoId ? newValue : item)));
 }
```

Comment: огромное спасибо! И сам так делал (у меня не получалосью,теперь убрал перед последним ретерном точку с запятой и все заработало!)Сейчас на гит заброшу и пойду учить вместо local storage добавление на сервер.

Comment: как добавить дату в список дел, нужно чтобы был список дел и справа  дата занесения, я так понимаю дату надо дописать в local storage? @ИльяПаймушкин помогите плиз! toLocaleString() [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1233266/Как-сделать-запись-текущей-даты-в-форму-и-сохранить-в-local-storage]