# Как сделать запись текущей даты в форму и сохранить в local storage?

Tags: reactjs, localstorage

как записать текущую дату в local storage  и затем чтобы выводилась в списке задач? думаю надо использовать let now = new Date().toLocaleDateString(); но дальше теряюсь.
Сайт: https://react-todo-app3.vercel.app Репозиторий на гит: https://github.com/paul76546/react-todo-app3

````
//import {reactLocalStorage} from 'reactjs-localstorage';
import TodoForm from './TodoForm';
import Todo from './Todo';

function TodoList() {
//const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);переделываем на 
let [todos, setTodos] = useState(localStorage.getItem('todos') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos')) : []);

//добавляем еще одну функцию
let setTodosWithSave = (newTodos) => {
 setTodos(newTodos);
 localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(newTodos));
};

let addTodo = todo => {
 if (!todo.text || /^\s*$/.test(todo.text)) {
   return;
 }

 let newTodos = [todo, ...todos];

 setTodosWithSave(newTodos);
 
};
//console.log(...todos);
//перед консоль лог было setTodos(newTodos);


//let updateTodo = (todoId, newValue) => {
 //if (!newValue.text || /^\s*$/.test(newValue.text)) {
   //return;
 //}
 
 //setTodos(prev => prev.map(item => (item.id === todoId ? newValue : item)));
 const updateTodo = (todoId, newValue) => {
   if (!newValue.text || /^\s*$/.test(newValue.text)) {
     return;
   }

   setTodosWithSave(todos.map(item => (item.id === todoId ? newValue : item)));
};
//setTodos(newTodos);
 //localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify('value'));
 //setTodosWithSave.push{'id', 'text'};
 //console.log(...todos);
//34  строка?
const removeTodo = id => {
 const removedArr = [...todos].filter(todo => todo.id !== id);

 setTodosWithSave(removedArr);
};

let completeTodo = id => {
 let updatedTodos = todos.map(todo => {
   if (todo.id === id) {
     todo.isComplete = !todo.isComplete;
   }
   return todo;
 });
 setTodosWithSave(updatedTodos);
 
}

//h1 заголовок Какие планы на сегодня? 
// (What's the Plan for Today?) по английскому
// меняю на Список дел на сегодня
//ставлю обратно 
return (
 <>
   <h1>Список дел на сегодня</h1>
   <TodoForm onSubmit={addTodo} />
   <Todo
     todos={todos}
     completeTodo={completeTodo}
     removeTodo={removeTodo}
     updateTodo={updateTodo}
   />
 </>
);
};

export default TodoList;    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне больше всего нравится [toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

в вашем файле `react-todo-app3/src/components/TodoForm.js`

```
const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    props.onSubmit({
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
        text: input,
        date: new Date().toISOString(),
    });
    setInput('');
};
```

Далее в файле `react-todo-app3/src/components/Todo.js`

```
return todos.map((todo, index) => (
    <div
      className={todo.isComplete ? 'todo-row complete' : 'todo-row'}
      key={index}
    >
  <div key={todo.id} onClick={() => completeTodo(todo.id)}>
    {todo.text}
  </div>
  <div>{todo.date}</div>
  <div className='icons'>
    <AiOutlineCloseSquare
      onClick={() => removeTodo(todo.id)}
      className='delete-icon'
    />
    <FiEdit3
      onClick={() => setEdit({ id: todo.id, value: todo.text })}
      className='edit-icon'
    />
  </div>
</div>
));
```

А дальше для того чтобы вывести в человеко-подобный вид, можно поиграть с форматами дат:)

Comment: Благодарен за быструю помощь @ИльяПаймушкин ! Вы просто мой спаситель! Утром в 5: 00  мне в шахту завтра на работу потом буду играть с форматами. Здоровья и с Крещением!

Comment: спасибо, хорошей работы:)

Comment: если будет возможность натолкните меня на следующий мой вопрос[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1238816/385177] Благодарен за вашу помощь!